# SSH connection to github is not working

Tags: git, github, ssh

I followed the github manual [Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) but I have the follow output:

```
$ ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/juan/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/juan/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/juan/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/juan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection to 192.30.252.131 timed out while waiting to read
```

- I use `archlinux`
- I don't have firewall
- My `~/.ssh/config` is empty and my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has default config.

Also, i have the follow files:

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 16K
drwx------  2 juan users 4.0K may  8 11:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 75 juan users 4.0K may  8 11:45 ../
-rw-------  1 juan users 1.7K may  7 23:22 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 juan users  403 may  7 23:22 id_rsa.pub
```

And when i do the follow, I get something different that expected.

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:KWw15AkdJnqJ3dZQ+t8uEdLoBpIlj0ELtgH1K7GWC1c /home/juan/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

I asked it already, but I don't know why I got negative votated. Please, I'm really lost, because I can't do push by https and I'm a newbie.